# Copy buffer absolute file path to the system clipboard

Tags: kill-ring

How can i copy the absolute path of the current open buffer to the system clipboard `(i.e. ctrl + shift + v) and not (ctrl + y)`

There are many solutions available for such copy, [1](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/03/27/copy-filename-to-the-clipboard/) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669511/the-function-to-show-current-files-full-path-in-mini-buffer) but all of them doesn't work outside the emacs application.

Comment: I see, Jordan has already answered a similar issue here - http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13194/how-can-i-clear-the-contents-of-the-clipboard-before-calling-clipboard-kill-regi. It works with emacs gui but not with emacs in terminal...

Comment: `kill-new` works fine for me for copying stuff to system clipboard with `x-select-enable-clipboard` and `x-select-enable-primary` set to `t` on RHEL 5.10. What is your OS? Also can you update your question as this is not specific to copying buffer file names?

Comment: `package-install xclip` and `(xclip-mode 1)` made it.. you guys are making my life beautiful.... on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Actually this is the possible duplicate then: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/11018/115